# Issue in converting javascript to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

Syntax issue in typescript..  I wrote code in javascript and try to put it in ts file. Made some changes, but still showing issues with cells.

```js
class X {
  public appendTableColumn() {
    var tbl = <HTMLTableElement>document.getElementById("myTable"); // table reference
    //var colnum= parseInt(tbl.rows[0].cells.length) - 1;
    // i;
    var m = parseInt(tbl.rows[0].cells.length) + 1;
    // open loop for each row and append cell
    for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
      var k = parseInt(i) + 1;

      //createCell(tbl.rows[i].insertCell(tbl.rows[i].cells.length), "R"+ tbl.rows.length +"C"+ k, 'col');
      this.createCell(
        tbl.rows[i].insertCell(tbl.rows[i].cells.length),
        "",
        "col",
      );
      var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i].cells;
      var btnName = "R" + k + "C" + m;
      x[tbl.rows[i].cells.length - 1].id = "td" + btnName;
      x[tbl.rows[i].cells.length - 1].innerHTML =
        '<button class="button" onclick="reply_click(this.id);" id=' +
        btnName +
        ">Manage Items</button>";
      //alert(btnName);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error you're getting?

Comment: What error you are getting? You should specify it.

Comment: @JSONDerulo Is there a resource about what you said? I think you're wrong.

Comment: @JSONDerulo `var`s are totally allowed in TS.

Comment: Where is createCell implemented?

Comment: @AKX Property cell does not exist on the type Element

Comment: @Ali Property cell does not exist on the type Element

Comment: @Gaotter   public createCell(cell, text, style) {
    var div = document.createElement('div'), 
        txt = document.createTextNode(text); 
    div.appendChild(txt);           
   
    cell.appendChild(div);                  
      }

Comment: @DevTry ok, but in the code you are listing, that is missing from the X class, so this.createCell would be undefined.

Comment: @Gaotter   Issue showing is :  Property cell does not exist on the type Element

Comment: @DevTry Ok, you are probably missing a cast like this one: 
document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i].cells; 
document.getElementById("myTable") returns a Element that you have to cast to a table element. Like you are doing in the var tbl...

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById`is only guaranteed to return an `HTMLElement`, but you're implicitly expecting it to be a table, which TypeScript can't guarantee because it doesn't look at your HTML code (among other reasons).

When you have an element type assumption like this, what you need to do is use a type assertion.

```
var x = (<HTMLTableElement>document.getElementById("myTable")).rows[i].cells;
```

As an aside, you don't need to pass variables of type `number` to `parseInt`. The following lines:

```
var m = parseInt(tbl.rows[0].cells.length) + 1;
// ...
var k = parseInt(i) + 1;
```

Should instead be written as:

```
var m = tbl.rows[0].cells.length + 1;
// ...
var k = i + 1;
```